# How to count the number multiple strings appear in another string list by group?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, stringr, grepl

Now I have two data, *name* and *text*, and I want to calculate the number of occurrences of each name in *name* in the current year in *text*, that is, to generate data *result*. How to achieve this? I tried *lapply* and *grepl*, but both failed. Thanks a lot!

```
name=data.table(year=c(2018,2019,2020),
                  name0=list(c("A","B","C"),c("B","C"),c("D","E","F")))
text=data.table(year=c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2020),
                text0=list(c("DEF","BG","CG"),c("ART","CWW"),c("DLK","BU","FO"),
                           c("A45","11B","C23"),c("EIU","CM")))
result=data.table(year=c(2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020),
                 name0=c("A","B","C","B","C","D","E","F"),
                 count=c(1,1,2,2,1,0,1,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A merge on unlisted values will work:

```r
library(data.table)
merge(
  name[, .(name0 = unlist(name0)), by = .(year)],
  text[, .(name0 = unlist(strsplit(unlist(text0), ""))), by=.(year)][, ign := 1],
  by = c("year", "name0"), all.x = TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE
)[,.(count = sum(!is.na(ign))), by = .(year, name0)]
#     year  name0 count
#    <num> <char> <int>
# 1:  2018      A     1
# 2:  2018      B     1
# 3:  2018      C     2
# 4:  2019      B     2
# 5:  2019      C     1
# 6:  2020      D     0
# 7:  2020      E     1
# 8:  2020      F     0
```

The `ign` variable is so that we can force `all.x=TRUE` yet account for those that were not found in `y`.

---

Slower but perhaps more memory-frugal method:

```r
namelong <- name[, .(name0 = unlist(name0)), by = .(year)]
namelong
#     year  name0
#    <num> <char>
# 1:  2018      A
# 2:  2018      B
# 3:  2018      C
# 4:  2019      B
# 5:  2019      C
# 6:  2020      D
# 7:  2020      E
# 8:  2020      F

func <- function(yr, nm) text[year == yr, sum(grepl(nm, unlist(text0)))]
namelong[, count := do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN=func), unname(namelong)))]
#     year  name0 count
#    <num> <char> <int>
# 1:  2018      A     1
# 2:  2018      B     1
# 3:  2018      C     2
# 4:  2019      B     2
# 5:  2019      C     1
# 6:  2020      D     0
# 7:  2020      E     1
# 8:  2020      F     0
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your code and there is no problem in example, but my actual data is very large, and the rows of `text` are more than 100 million, so R reports Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?). Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: See if my edit offers a way to do it. It's going to be slower (it's not far-removed from a `for` loop) but expands less into memory.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was solved.